# The autoreload module is not an IPython extension

Tags: python, ipython

- When I input `%load_ext autoreload`
- the result is :

```
In [1]: %load_ext autoreload
The autoreload module is not an IPython extension.
```

my ipython version is 3.7.6, my ipython version is 7.11.1

I try to do something, but not working.

```
pip install ipython==7.0.1
pip install ipython==7.11.1
```

I don't know how to deal with, please help me, thanks.

Comment: How was iPython installed in the first place? Did you try running it inside a virtual environment?

Comment: Are you using IPython directly in your terminal? Or are you running it from another program?

Comment: @Jalo , Hi, I actually running it inside a virtual environment, but I worked it well before, maybe after install a package, it's not working. I try to using IPython directly in terminal, like anaconda prompt. I also trying in the jupyter lab/notebook, I'm sure the env is right.

Comment: What happens if you try it on a *new* virtual environment with just IPython? Can you also [edit] to share the packages installed on your virtual env? (`pip freeze > requirements.txt`). I can't seem to reproduce your issue on my env.